# Lost and Found part 3 - Krom's Compass

Tags: darksiders-2

I've been all through this place but i can't seem to find Krom's compass. Going back through and finished up secondary quests. Help?

Answer (score 3):

In the lost temple look at your dungeon map. There is a large white circle indicating a elevator north of the circle is a green open door in that room is a water shrine the compass in in the center of the alter. Look for the windchimes.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier to see this video showing the exact location: